# Add PHPWord to Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, phpword

I need to add the quite excellent PHPWord - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord to a Joomla 2.5 project.

I have added the PHPWord files to the plugins folder (might not be the correct choice) and have the following code

```
    $phpWord = new \libraries\PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
```

The class is not found as it is not autoloading. How would I load these classes in Joomla and it there a better folder than plugins that will will autoload?

I have added these lines

```
   JLoader::discover('PhpWord', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/PhpOffice/PhpWord/'); 
   $phpWord = new PhpWord;
```

Inside the PhpWord folder is Phpword.php and autoloader.php, as well as several other scripts.

Comment: Have a look at the official implementation for a custom library: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions

Comment: Thanks Lodder, have tried following the guide, with no luck.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the process you've tried and the code you're now currently using?

Comment: there is allready exisitng phpword joomla library here https://github.com/vdespa/PHPWord-Joomla-Library  hope it might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment above in [Using_own_library_in_your_extensions](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions) they explain how to import a library for Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.

Now assuming that the tutorial is correct and `JLoader::discover` is working I would say that the issue is that you have PHPWord in the plugin folder and with JLoader::discover you are searching in `/libraries/PhpOffice/PhpWord/`.

So

1. copy /PhpOffice/PhpWord/ in libraries
2. try to use again `JLoader::discover('PhpWord', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/PhpOffice/PhpWord/');`

Reading the documentation of PhpWord I found that you can also directly require the library and use it in this way:

```php
// be sure that the path match in your joomla
require_once 'libraries/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. My code used JPATH_LIBRARIES and works perfectly.                                                                                   require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/PhpOffice/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

// Creating the new document...
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();